# POST doesnt work correctly

Tags: php, html

i have a code in tpl:

```
   <form action="build.php?id={id}" method="post">
   <input width="80" type='submit' height='20' value='{uzsakyti_svente}' name='uzsakyti1'>
   </form>
```

When i press the button action is going and automatically when action has ended page refreshed and firefox popup came out and let's me choose between reload pages and cancel, now this is the problem i don't want that i want that when action is complete page just refresh but the firefox table or other browser's tables won't came out, now any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Do you use a redirection in your built.php script ? It seems that your script refresh your page, and with Post request, the navigators purpose you to send the data again or not.

Comment: yes build.php is same file that i perform action anyway to do my thing in this case?

Comment: Post your build.php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to your page if catch a Post request, in your build.php file :

```
if (! empty( $_POST))
{
   // Update or insert your data in DB or whatever ...

   if ($data_ok)
   {
       header( 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other' );

       // You can add a param to display in your view that the form was posted
       header( 'Location: http://domain.com/build.php?posted=1' );
       exit();
   }
}

// Your main code goes here ...
```